# Possible to inject target hierarchy into make target environment?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If I have a Make file like:

```
a: b
    echo in a
b: c
    echo in b
c:
    echo in c
```

Is there a way for target `c` to know the nodes of the make dependency graph, `a`->`b`->`c`, that happen to be invoking the `c` target?

Can this be made available in the environment of each sub-$SHELL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, in make, there is no way to determine from within a recipe what path of the dependency graph was walked by make to decide to build that target.

You can add such a thing yourself, if you're willing to restrict yourself to GNU Make features, using [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#index-target_002dspecific-variables) for example:

```
a: b
        @echo in a: $(TARGS)
b: c
        @echo in b: $(TARGS)
c:
        @echo in c: $(TARGS)

TARGS :=

a: TARGS += a
b: TARGS += b
c: TARGS += c
```

will get you:

```
in c: a b c
in b: a b
in a: a
```

Comment: Fantastic. And I can add it into the environment like `c: export TARGS += c`

Comment: You can just set the original to `export TARGS :=` and it will be exported to all shells (unless you only want to export to that specific recipe of course)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with recursive make:

```
a:
    $(MAKE) DEPCHAIN="$(DEPCHAIN)->$@" b
    echo in a
b:
    $(MAKE) DEPCHAIN="$(DEPCHAIN)->$@" c
    echo in b
c:
    echo "in c $(DEPCHAIN)"
```

There's also the `--trace` argument to make, which is useful for debugging why a target was invoked, which might be more useful to your problem.